# Can I sort column B into column C using only functions/formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Without going into the why... I have a large column of formulas in column B.  I would like column C to contain the SORTED VALUES of those formulas.  If I change the parameters of the formulas, column B will re-calculate.  I want column C to automatically re-calculate, also.

I know I can copy column B and paste-special/values into column C and then hit Sort.  I'm trying to avoid that process for a number of reasons.  Those reasons preclude using a macro.

Can it be done?  I'm on Excel 2011 for Mac.

Comment: What about http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/10/22/sorting-text-in-excel-using-formulas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `LARGE` ([official doc](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db)) and `SMALL` ([official doc](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/small-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)) functions.

Perhaps you may find performance issues with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values are in cell B1:B6 (doesn't matter if the values are hard coded or calculated by formula), then this Formula can be entered in Range C1 as a Matrix Formula (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT) and copied down:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(ROW(B1),RANK($B$1:$B$6,$B$1:$B$6,0),0),1)
```

You must ensure that the part of the fuction that says `Row(B1)` calculates to 1, as this creates the index by which the formula looksup the rank of the number.